# how to generate a ssh key in windows?

Tags: windows, github, cmd, ssh-keys

I'm following [this](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/README.html) to generate a ssh key on windows 8.1, but if I press enter key when asked to enter file in which to save the key I get error `could not create the directory '//.ssh'`

now if instead of pressing enter I enter "id_rsa", then after doing `clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, I get `The system cannot find the path specified`.

Is there any way around this? I can switch to ubuntu but I want to do this on windows.

Comment: I just use puttygen: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html - not really a SO question, though

Comment: just used it, it's amazing, but one more question, if you read this [guide][1],  there's something about the email address  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$your_email"`, why is it needed ? If I use the key generated without this command will this cause any issue ?
  
[1]: http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/README.html

Comment: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ssh-keygen.htm The -C is a "comment" - it's used for your own identification, and shouldn't be necessary for the key to work

Answer (score 5):

The best way to find your ssh keys is:

1. create an account in Github
2. download Github application on desktop and login with your credentials
3. after 1 min, Go to Github website --> login --> go to setting --> In left side click on ssh keys, here you can find your ssh keys.

Answer (score 2):

```
could not create the directory '//.ssh'
```

That means $HOME isn't properly defined. Try and type first:

```
export HOME=/c/Users/<yourUsername>
```

Then `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$your_email"` should work.

Note that if you were to type the same command in a (DOS) shell launched with the [git-cmd.bat included in a standard Git for Windows (msysgit)](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat), `%HOME%` wold be set for you (to `%USERPROFILE%`), and the same `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$your_email"` would work too.